# Import MS-Excel columns to MS-Word as Comments

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Situation: 
I am trying to search through a word document for Keyword/IDs contained in an excel, and add comments from the spreadsheet to the word document for every occurrence of the Keyword/IDs then save. The sample code I have runs through the list of Keyword/IDs, but only comments the first occurrence

Give: 
The word  file is located at C:\Test\ACBS.docx  and the  excel executing the VBA macro is located separately.  In the Excel the search term variable “FindWord” is in column A , and the comment is the variable “CommentWord” in column B.

Problem:
How can I get this to search through the entire word document and comment each occurrence of the Keyword/IDs?

Code:

```
Sub Comments_Excel_to_Word()
'Author: Paul Keahey
'Date: 2017-10-30
'Name:Comments_Excel_to_Word
'Purpose: To bring in comments From Excel to Word.
'Comments: None

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objSelection
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Test\ACBS.docx")
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
Dim oRng As Word.range
Set oRng = objSelection.range
Set oScope = oRng.Duplicate
Dim oCol As New Collection
Dim FindWord As String
Dim CommentWord As String
Dim I As Integer



'initalize list of varables


For I = 2 To range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

FindWord = Sheet1.range("A" & I).Value
CommentWord = Sheet1.range("B" & I).Value

 With oRng.Find
    .Text = FindWord
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    Do While .Execute = True
        If oRng.InRange(oScope) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            'MsgBox "oRng.InRange(oScope)"
            oCol.Add oRng.Text, oRng.Text
            On Error GoTo 0
                oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                Else
             ActiveDocument.Comments.Add oRng, CommentWord

                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

    End With
Next I

objDoc.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm no Word expert, but the `ActiveDocument.Comments.Add` line is in the Else block of your `If`, which is IMHO never reached since `oRng.InRange(oScope)` is always `True`.

Comment: The oRng.InRange(oScope) is not always true, because this code does add the comments to the word document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the Word component of this setup, but if you want to list all comments in your Excel file, you can use the script below to do that.

```
Sub ShowCommentsAllSheets()
'Update 20140508
Dim commrange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Set newWs = Application.Worksheets.Add
newWs.Range("A1").Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("Sheet", "Address", "Value", "Comment")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set commrange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    If Not commrange Is Nothing Then
        i = newWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rng In commrange
            i = i + 1
            newWs.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(ws.Name, rng.Address, rng.Value, rng.Comment.Text)
        Next
    End If
    Set commrange = Nothing
Next
newWs.Cells.WrapText = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```